# using matlab production server(MPS) and webfigure

Tags: servlets, matlab-deployment

I would like to know how to pass a plot from matlab to be displayed as a webfigure on a servlet page. Note that I'm using the MPS. Hence I'm not packaging the matlab code into java but just using a client proxy to the matlab function.

My eg matlab function:

```
function varargout = mymagicplot(in,displayPlot)
    x = magic(in);
    varargout{1} = x;
    if (strcmp(displayPlot, 'Plot'))
       varargout{2} = {plot(x)};
end
```

On the servlet side:

```
interface MatlabMagic {
  public Object[] mymagicplot(int num_outargs, int size, String plotOption) throws IOException, MATLABException;
}
```

Question is how to code the display of the plot as a webfigure on the servlet page?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround by splitting my matlab code into two functions.

First function is used by the client proxy.

```
function m = mymagic(in)
    m = magic(in);
end
```

Second function is packaged into java classes by the library compiler.

```
function returnfigure = mygetwebfiguremagicplot(in)
   h = figure;
   set(h, 'Visible', 'off');
   plot(in);
   returnfigure = webfigure(h);
   close(h);
end
```

In this way, I can access the mymagic function .ctf in the MPS to return the results to the servlet and plot it as a webfigure using the java classes created from the second function matlab code.

This is just one possible workable solution that I can think of.